# How to retrieve only the current element while check the previous and next value in array (python)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, iterator

I am re-visiting how to write in Python to iterate over the array list and I am trying to check the previous and next value, and just print out the current value in the list. For example, in my list I have ["NotActive", "Active", "Depart", "Land", "Arrived"]

The default is "NotActive" and I am trying to get currentValue as "Depart", and I want to check the next value is "Land" and previous value as "Active". However, I keep getting the current value as "Land"

I created a for loop that can iterate through the list. It iterates, but not sure why it won't go to Arrived if it iterated all the way.

Any idea what happened

```
 status_array = request.data['status'] -> here is the list fields listed above
 result = "NotActive" -> default value which now is the current value

try:
  for name in status_array:
     status = Flight.objects.get(name=name)
     status_id = status.status_id
except Flight.DoesNotExist:
   listed_result = {
      "result": status_id
   } -> here is the status_array for request.data['status'] the request going to be print out
print(listed_result) = ["Landed"]
```

Comment: You can use [enumerate](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-access-previous-and-next-values-when-looping-through-a-list-in-python) to access previous and next values in a list in a loop.

Comment: `for previous, current, next in zip(data, data[1:], data[2:]):`

Comment: in code you should use `#` insitead of `->`. OR at least `# ->` to put it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can consider implementing a Python DoubleLinkedList class so that your data can goes inside this data structure.

A double linked list contains a few nodes, each of which has a *previous* node and a *next* node. In a node, we can store data. And, with the help of (public) attributes, we can actually retrieve the data from either the previous node or the next one, given a current one to refer to. My reference is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/).

Comment: How would it go from a double linked list here, reverse and forward? Would it print 1 result like a specific element we want to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the previous and next you can just have a temp variable for the previous.

```
#Set the previous/next to empty
prev = ''
next = ''
for i in range(len(status_array)):
    #Check if we are at the end
    if status_array[i] == 'Arrived':
        #Get the previous information
        status_prev = Flight.objects.get(name=prev)
        prev_status_id = status_prev.status_id
        #Get the current information
        status = Flight.objects.get(name=status_array[i])
        status_id = status.status_id
    #Check to see if we are at the start
    if prev == '':
        next = status_array[i+1]
        status_next = Flight.objects.get(name=next)
        next_status_id = status_next.status_id
        #Set the current to be the previous
        prev = status_array[i]
        #Get the current status info
        status = Flight.objects.get(name=status_array[i])
        status_id = status.status_id

    #Else we have a previous
    else:
        #Get the previous information
        status_prev = Flight.objects.get(name=prev)
        prev_status_id = status_prev.status_id
        #Get the current information
        status = Flight.objects.get(name=status_array[i])
        status_id = status.status_id
        #Make sure we have not 'Arrived'
        if status_array[i] != 'Arrived':
            next = status_array[i+1]
            status_next = Flight.objects.get(name=next)
            next_status_id = status_next.status_id
        #Update the previous
        prev = status_array[i]
```

I hope this points in the right direction but as mentioned it would be easier to attempt this with a doubly linked list. Cheers!

Comment: I find that from my version to yours it prints the same result where I just want to print the current element. However in mine it prints the current element[4], and I retrieve your element[4] and it prints the same output as mine. It never hits 'arrived', when I put arrived in the request body it prints empty string. Any idea why